# How to a convert a single-direction linked list with digits in the data to an int number

Tags: java, list

I'm having some trouble coming up with the code for converting a single-linked list(-->) into a number(presumably long\double to accomodate longer lists).

The nodes are made of an `int` instance variable and `IntNode` pointer to the next object.

For example:
if the list is 1->2->3->4->5, then the number would be: 12345.

Would appreciate any guidance!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
String sNum = "";

for (int x : list) { // assuming your linked-list implements Iterable
    sNum += x;
}

long num = Long.parseLong(sNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way you'd convert the string "12345" into a number if you couldn't use `parseInt()`.

Here is pseudo-code for doing it, applicable to most languages and sources of digits.

```
number = 0
loop through digits:
    number = 10 * number + digit
return number
```

In pure functional languages, you'd do it similarly using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3);
    l.add(4);
    l.add(5);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer integer : l) {
        sb.append(integer);
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
}
```